# how Scrolling a SurfaceView ,which is behind a Softkeyboard.

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

i have a SurfaceView and it is a fragment which is embeded in a Framelayout.The surfaceview is similar to MS word document and this view  is updated by C code.
the issue is when ever i touch any where on the document(Surfaceview) a indication is recieved from C code by which we show a Softkeyboard in android .So the requirement is that while the softkeyboard is shown the behind Surfaceview has to be scrolled ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//follow the link

from the SO

[android-is-software-keyboard-shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

Comment: @Padma Kumar, Can you give brief description? What is SO here? and how to and at where should we write this line?

Comment: @anddev SO- StackoverFlow, sorry I missed the link. now edited.